# Naming convention for design documents in large CouchDB database

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have a very large couchDB database that I host on Cloudant. One of the early noob mistakes I made was keep all my views under one design document. When I made a change to the design document by adding a new view, it would compile the design document again and make the database unavailable for a while.

After I talked to Cloudant, they told me it's good practice to have multiple design documents, and after doing some reading, it looks like CouchDB runs one view server per design document.

Now as in true startup fashion, we are constantly adding new features and hence new updates to the database (which is in production). Whenever I want to add a new view, I make a new design document and add the view to it.

With that background two questions.

1. Is this the right approach?
2. What naming scheme should my design documents follow?

Comment: May be on topic at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a master design document that provides a [rewrite](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Rewriting_urls) to another design document that contains the actual view you want to execute.  The master design document shouldn't have any views so you can feel free to update that as often as you need.  With this approach, the naming convention is up to you as long as you reference it correctly in the main design document's rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not a bad approach. Given that views within a design doc are processed together, more design documents gives you greater parallelism when building views (assuming the cluster can handle it). You could also look at using [Cloudant Query](https://cloudant.com/blog/introducing-cloudant-query) which provides an abstraction layer over map/reduce so you don't need to care about your design doc names.

In general, I would advise giving your design documents meaningful names - if you do need to add new views to an existing design doc, you can use [this trick](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_deploy_view_changes_in_a_live_environment).